# How to Convert MySQLi to PDO using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to send this to datatables but I get this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: totalRecordwithFilter in C:\xampp\htdocs\dov\action\user_list.php on line 79
> {"draw":1,"iTotalRecords":"2","iTotalDisplayRecords":null,"aaData":[]}

```
include "database_Connection.php";    
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
$row = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage = $_POST['length']; 
$columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; 
$columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; 
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];     
$searchValue = $_POST['search']['value'];    
$data = array();
```

I get the error from this part but i cant seem to see it.

### Fetch records and ## Total number of records with filtering

```
$searchQuery = "";

if ($searchValue != '') {
    $query1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS allcount FROM users WHERE
        Firstname LIKE ? OR Othername LIKE ? OR AccessLevel LIKE ? ");
    $query1->execute(['%'.$searchValue.'%', '%'.$searchValue.'%', '%'.$searchValue.'%']);
    $records = $query1->fetch();
    $totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

 if($query1->rowCount()>0)
 {

   foreach($results as $row)
    {
        //Update Button
    $updateButton = "<a href='modify.php?".$row['UserId']."' class='btn' style='color: blue'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>";
        //Delete Button
    $deleteButton = "<a href='delete.php?".$row['UserId']."' class='btn' style='color: red'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";
        //Action button
    $action = $updateButton." ".$deleteButton;

    $data[] = array(
            "UserId" => $row['UserId'], 
            "Firstname" => $row['Firstname'],
            "Othername" => $row['Othername'],
            "AccessLevel" => $row['AccessLevel'],
            "AddedDate" => $row['AddedDate'],
            "Action" => $action
        );
    }
 }
}
```

### Response

```
$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
    "aaData" => $data
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You have to write your own code. That means reading up on these topics and then convert the code yourself. If you then encounter a real problem you can ask us for help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and explain what issue(s) you are having. PDO doesn't just prevent SQL injections, you will still need to rewrite queries. Mysqli can use prepared statements as well.

Comment: I have a long code and the system doesnt allow me to paste all

Comment: If there is anything **not** working, please edit your question to contain more details

Comment: `var_dump($searchValue)` gives what?

Comment: should i try this @user3783243?

Comment: ```var_dump($searchValue);``` It gives nothing

Comment: So `if ($searchValue != '') {` is FALSE and you never enter the conditional that populates value, and executes query. What about `var_dump($_POST['search']['value'], $_POST, $_POST['search'])`?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing, regardless of whether you use mysqli or PDO, is to always bind parameters instead of concatenating it with SQL. You must always use prepared statements with parameter binding.

Before you create a prepared statement you have to establish a connection with PDO. This is how to do it.

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8mb4", 'username', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);
```

Then you can prepare and execute a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS allcount FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$records = $stmt->fetch();
$totalRecords = $records['allcount'];
```

To bind parameters you have to put placeholders in the SQL and then pass the values in execute.

```
if ($searchValue != '') {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS allcount FROM users WHERE
        Firstname LIKE ? OR 
        Othername LIKE ? OR 
        AccessLevel LIKE ? ");
    $stmt->execute(['%'.$searchValue.'%', '%'.$searchValue.'%', '%'.$searchValue.'%']);
    $records = $stmt->fetch();
    $totalRecords = $records['allcount'];
}
```

Comment: Imho, answering questions that contains little to no indication that they've even tried to solve it themselves just does this site a disservice. The OP (and other users) will just start treating this site as a free coding service. It also sends very mixed signals when we sometimes close questions for that exact reason and then sometimes answer them.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson We never close questions because of lack of effort. There is no such close reason. As long as the question is answerable and reasonably scoped there is no reason not to answer. After all, Stack Overflow is a free coding service, there's plenty of free code here.

Comment: By that locic, questions that are basically just specifications are valid here? "I want this and I want that..." with no code or effort? Just trying to understand when and where the line goes. And also _"We never close questions because of lack of effort. There is no such close reason"_ is not entirely true for how things really work here though. Sure, there's no close reason with that exact text, but those questions tends to be closed with "needs more focus" while the comments tells the real reason.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, as long as they are reasonably focused. We have plenty of such questions. How to do X? etc. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284599/do-questions-have-to-have-an-attempted-solution?noredirect=1&lq=1 If you are still unclear and want to discuss more, please open a new Meta topic.

Comment: I have tried the above and it doesnt give me any error nor gives the result

Comment: @Bigboss That means that no entries match your search criteria

Comment: @Dharman There should be at least default data in the form before the search query.